# getStaticProps is not working. Can someone help me?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './page.module.css'


export async function getStaticProps (){
    const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    const todos  = await data.json();
    console.log(todos);
    return {
        props: {todos}
    }
}

export default function Todos ({todos}) {
  return (
    <>
        <h1>Todos</h1>
        <ul className={styles.todolist}>
            {todos}
        </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

`getStaticProps` is not working, `console.log()` it doesn't show anything.

I would like it to show a list of todos

Comment: which nextjs version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the right location, with the code you provide `getStaticProps` should work, and in fact, it is running on the server so you cannot see logs from the browser console, however, you can find it in the terminal console.